# Не могу установить symfony 4.4, ошибка InvalidArgumentException

Tags: php, symfony, composer

В composer пишу команду:

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton:^4.4 my_project_name
```

Вылазит ошибка:

> [InvalidArgumentException] Could not find package symfony/website-skeleton with version 4.4.

Что я делаю не так и как установить версию 4.4?

Comment: Какая версия PHP у вас? `php -v`

Comment: PHP 7.3.9 только что проверил

Answer (score 0):

У вас версия `php` ниже чем 7.1.3 по этому вы не можете установить версию симфони 4.4

Answer (score 0):

В общем перешёл на php 7.1. В composer прописал обычную команду установки и он сам мне установил symfony версию 4.4.

Comment: Нет ровным счетом ни единого аргумента за то, чтобы оставаться на версии 7.1

https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php